# Countable Ordinals

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, ordinals

In an intro topology class we briefly brought up ordinal numbers during a conversation of transfinite induction. I believe I understand how the ordinal numbers work, at least up to $\omega^\omega$.

It seems that a set of cardinality $\omega^\omega$ must be uncountable, since $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ is uncountable, but on wikipedia it says that $\omega^\omega$ as an ordinal is countable (as are many ordinals after it). I guess that past a certain point it does not make complete sense to relate the cardinal and ordinal numbers of a set, but is there an intuitive example of a countable set with ordinal number $\omega^\omega$? If not how would one go about proving that it was countable?

Comment: **See especially** [Intuition for $\omega^\omega$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336373/intuition-for-omega-omega?), **and also see** [Visualizations of ordinal numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599022/visualizations-of-ordinal-numbers) **and** [Understanding countable ordinals (as trees, step by step)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603556/understanding-countable-ordinals-as-trees-step-by-step) **and** [Easy visualizations of small countable ordinals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627291/easy-visualizations-of-small-countable-ordinals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cardinal exponentiation and ordinal exponentiation are fundamentally different things; it's unfortunate that they use the same notation. Some old books write "${}^\beta\alpha$" for the cardinal exponentiation "$\alpha^\beta$," but that's very much not in fashion. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation.)

- In cardinal exponentiation, "$\kappa^\mu$" is the cardinality of the set of all functions from $\mu$ to $\kappa$.
- Ordinal exponentiation is defined inductively: $\alpha^0=1$, $\alpha^{\beta+1}=\alpha^\beta\cdot \alpha$, and $\alpha^\lambda=\sup_{\beta<\lambda}\alpha^\beta$ for $\lambda$ a limit ordinal. In particular, the *ordinal* exponentiation $2^\omega$ is just $\omega$ - which makes it very frustrating that the symbol "$2^\omega$" is, universally, used to refer to the set of functions from $\omega$ to 2!

In general, you have to read context carefully.

Comment: Aren't all cardinals also ordinals, though?

Comment: @mrp Yes, but cardinal exponentiation and ordinal exponentiation are two very different things. For clarity, write them as "$*$" and "$\otimes$" - the point is, even if $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are cardinals, $\kappa*\lambda$ will be very different from $\kappa\otimes \lambda$.

Comment: There is a similar issue with addition, but less troublesome – the sum of $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ as ordinals may not be the same as their sum as cardinals.

Comment: A bit of pre-emptive clarification: It's less troublesome because cardinal addition is rarely something we care about, whereas both cardinal and ordinal exponentiation are important.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks Noah, this was really helpful.